# Geometry: how to get the radius of a circle with just a chord of the circle

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

Answer: Able to find area with statement 1) The length of the segment AB is 10

Above are two statements asking whether I can solve for the shaded areas given the information they have provided.

For my answer I said that I can't get the answer with the two statements individually, but can get the answer if I were to look at both statements and use the information given from them. Am I able to get the radius without knowing the relationship to the chord to the center of the circle?

Comment: Well, they are sufficient individually if you are looking for the grey shaded area.

Answer (score 2):

The shaded area
is the difference between
the areas of the
two semicircles.

Also,
by Pythagoras,
$(AB/2)^2
=R^2-r^2
$.

This gives what you want.